# Architectural Design to avoid circular dependency

Tags: c#, circular-dependency

I have an **Adaptor** with finds **Sources** and returns it. But I need a keep a reference of the Adaptor with all its sources. But this Design will create a circular dependency.

**IAdaptor** need a function with returns a list of **ISource**, and each **ISource** needs to keep a reference of it own **Adaptor**.

ISource is kept in a Project 1 and IAdaptor in Project 2

How do I accomplish this, without creating a circular dependency with each other?

Comment: Define the common interfaces in a third assembly and reference that in the implementation assemblies. Beyond that, you may need to use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) of some sort. Consider using an [IoC container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), like [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It looks IAdaptor and ISource are really tightly coupled. If it reflect your business model, just keep them in single project.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you mean: an actual assembly reference circular dependency? Or if you mean a a circular reference within the types themselves?

Comment: What do your Source need from your Adaptor?

Comment: if you ask the Source to do something it tells its adapter to do that for it.

Comment: actual assembly reference circular dependency @Simon

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to take a look at what functionalities ISource really need from IAdaptor: what methods on IAdaptor are called from ISource implementation, and are those methods really tied with IAdaptor.

In some situations, it may be appropriate to move those functionalities out of IAdaptor as a separate and more generic interface (I'll call it ISourceDependency), and put it in the same assembly of ISource. ISource would depend on ISourceDependency instead of IAdaptor, and thus the circular dependency is removed. Then you just needs to let the adaptors implement ISourceDependency in addition to IAdaptor.

If you find the methods on ISourceDependency really tied with the logic of IAdapter, then it'd be better just to put IAdapter in the same assembly as ISource.